# Proper way to get data from multi dim array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Hi following is my array data:

I am trying to get the highlighted part of the picture.

This is an associative array so far I have tried this:

```
<?php

for($i = 0 ; $i < count($ad['all_atr']) ; $i++)
{
    $atr_n= $ad[$i]['all_atr']['atr_n'];
    $atr_v= $ad[$i]['all_atr']['atr_v'];
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $atr_n;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $atr_v;?></td>
</tr>
<?php
....
```

but gives error 'Undefined offset: 0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access it, point the array first, then the index:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($ad['all_atr']); $i++)
{
    $atr_n = $ad['all_atr'][$i]['a_name'];
    $atr_v = $ad['all_atr'][$i]['a_val'];
}
```

Or with using foreach:

```
foreach($ad['all_atr'] as $values) {
    $atr_n = $values['a_name'];
    $atr_v = $values['a_val'];
}
```

Comment: it says Undefined index: atr_n

Comment: @Umerm change it to `a_name`

Answer (score 0):

Just check that the data is set, and isn't empty before adding them to $atr_n & $atr_v :

```
if (isset($ad['all_atr'][$i]['a_name']) && isset($ad['all_atr'][$i]['a_val']) && !empty($ad['all_atr'][$i]['a_name']) && !empty($ad['all_atr'][$i]['a_val'])) {
    $atr_n = $ad['all_atr'][$i]['a_name'];
    $atr_v = $ad['all_atr'][$i]['a_val'];
}
```

Comment: Change `atr_n` and `atr_v` to `a_name` and `a_val` respectively.

Comment: @Amal Murali,Yes corrected,I have seen hilighted part of question so I have used those.Thanks for notified.